# Error code: the programs runs but when I click on the courses button I get the error below

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.mystudy/com.example.mystudy.Courses}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(int)'
> on a null object reference

```
public class Courses extends AppCompatActivity {

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_courses);

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigator);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.courses);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.dashboard:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.home:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.courses:
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

this is the xml for activity_courses:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:text="Manage"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="My Courses"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="373dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="204dp"
    android:text="SWE 6653  \nSoftware Architecture"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="359dp"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
    android:text="+ Add a course"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It also, tells me to check this line of code: "bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.courses);"

Comment: share xml code for `activity_courses`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm still learning how to use stackoverflow, but you asked that I provided the xml code I have and also, provided the error I have and the activity that contains the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the BottomNavigationViewId you uesed `bottom_navigator`

```
 bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigator);
```

is correct or not.

Comment: yes it is correct, it error also, tells me to check this line of code: "bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.courses);"